# Numpy to pyTorch: are there different data types?

Tags: numpy, pytorch

**Question**: Can somebody help me to align this two approaches of data generation so that both of them can be used by the nn-model below ? When using appraoch (2) with `numpy` and `torch.from_numpy(x)` a run time error occurs ("*expected scalar type Float but found Double*")

For **data generation** I have these two approaches:

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

def get_training_data_1():
    x = torch.randn(batch_size, n_in)
    y = torch.tensor([[1.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0]])   
    return x,y

def get_training_data_2():
    x = np.random.rand(batch_size, n_in)
    y = np.array([[1.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0]])
    
    x = torch.from_numpy(x)
    y = torch.from_numpy(y)
    return x,y

n_in, n_h, n_out, batch_size = 2, 5, 1, 10
x, y = get_training_data_2()
```

With this **model** I run into problems when using appraoch (2) with `numpy` and `torch.from_numpy(x)`, while it is OK when using approach (1)

```
#---- Create a NN-model
model = nn.Sequential( nn.Linear(n_in, n_h),     # hidden layer
                       nn.ReLU(),                # activation layer
                       nn.Linear(n_h, n_out),    # output layer
                       nn.Sigmoid() )            # final 0, 1 rounding

#---- Construct the loss function
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

#---- Construct the optimizer (Stochastic Gradient Descent in this case)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.1)

#---- Gradient Descent
for epoch in range(1501):
    y_pred = model(x)                       # Forward pass: Compute predicted y by passing x to the model
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)             # Compute and print loss
    if epoch%50 == 0:
        print(epoch, loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()                   # Zero gradients, perform a backward pass, and update the weights.
    loss.backward()                         # perform a backward pass (backpropagation)
    optimizer.step()                        # Update the parameters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default floating point type in `torch` is `float32` (i.e. single precision).  In NumPy the default is `float64` (double precision).  Try changing `get_training_data_2` so that it explicitly sets the data type of the numpy arrays `numpy.float32` before converting them to torch tensors:

```
def get_training_data_2():
    x = np.random.rand(batch_size, n_in).astype(np.float32)
    y = np.array([[1.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0]],
                 dtype=np.float32)
    
    x = torch.from_numpy(x)
    y = torch.from_numpy(y)
    return x,y
```

---

*Note.* With the newer NumPy random API, you can generate `float32` samples directly instead of casting `float64` values to `float32`.

```
def get_training_data_2(rng):
    x = rng.random(size=(batch_size, n_in), dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.array([[1.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0]],
                 dtype=np.float32)
    
    x = torch.from_numpy(x)
    y = torch.from_numpy(y)
    return x,y


rng = np.random.default_rng()
x, y = get_training_data_2(rng)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there anything as `(....., dtype=torch.float32)` or `(.....).astype(torch.float32)` ?